# How to pass logger instance to my custom ModelBinderProvider in ConfigureServices?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I want to use ASP.NET Core's own logging and DI mechanism to perform some debug logging and tracing in my code. So my ModelBinderProvider looks like this:

```cs
public class MyOwnModelBinderProvider: // ... bla bla 
{
    public MyOwnModelBinderProvider(ILogger<MyOwnModelBinderProvider> logger)
    {
       // .. bla bla
    }
}
```

The recommended way to set up custom ModelBinderProviders in Startup.cs is like this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersAndViews(configure => 
        configure.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, 
            new MyOwnModelBinderProvider(/** WHAT TO PUT HERE? **/)));
}
```

I researched this and people have been creating separate instances of service providers by calling `BuildServiceProvider` in the ConfigureServices method but [David Fowler was strictly against that](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14587) as it might create a hanging instance of a service provider collection, never-freed.

It feels like quite an overhead for me too, just to pass a logger instance. Am I missing an obvious pattern here? I'm feeling like it should be much easier.

Comment: Why do you need to inject a logger? You can get one at the start of `GetBinder` from the `ModelBinderProviderContext`.

Comment: @yaakov You're right. I didn't know that, but I also wanted to know the proper way to do this for other classes too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways to do this:

1. In `GetBinder` the `ModelBinderProviderContext` has a `Services` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelbinderprovidercontext.services?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ModelBinding_ModelBinderProviderContext_Services).
2. You can configure MvcOptions outside of the call to `AddControllersAndViews`:

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<MvcOptions>()
                .Configure<ILoggerFactory>((options, loggerFactory) =>
                {
                    options.ModelBinderProviders.Add(new MyOwnModelBinderProvider(loggerFactory));
                });
```

This lets you pass dependencies to things that are created via options.